# Give a Viewport a 3D Effect in Godot

Tags: 3d, viewport, godot

I have two 3D sprites with Viewport textures in godot like this:
[image]
Portal 1 has the texture of what Portal 2 is seeing and vice versa. (Like Portal). I want it to have a 3D affect so when you're looking at it from the side it doesn't look flat like this:
[image]
Is there a way to implement a 3D effect. I already tried offsetting the camera when the character moves but it didn't work.
The Portal Layout is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you want is to move the `Camera` in the `Viewport` according to the transform of the main `Camera` (i.e. the current `Camera` in the main `Viewport`).

*We can do that, and then you find out that is not enough, but let us go one step at a time.*

So, the position of the main `Camera` is this:

```
var camera := get_tree().root.get_camera()
```

Yes, the root of the scene tree is a `Viewport`. So get the main `Camera` from it. *Well, unless you decide to put everything inside another `Viewport` (for example to control the render resolution independently from the screen resolution), then you use `get_camera` on that `Viewport`.*

And the transformation of the `Camera` is this:

```
var camera_transform := camera.get_camera_transform()
```

*Using `get_camera_transform` instead of `global_transform` is particularly important if you are using one of the classes that extend `Camera`.*

Now, we get the transform relative to the portal:

```
var relative_transform := portal.global_transform.affine_inverse() * camera_transform
```

And we use it like this:

```
var new_camera_transform := other_portal.global_transform * relative_transform
```

And, of course you need to give that transform to the `Camera` (the one on the other portal):

```
camera_of_the_other_portal.global_transform = new_camera_transform
```

---

And as I said above, that is not enough. Ideally we want to push the `Camera` to the other side of the portal, figure out the *portal* (i.e. the section of the viewing frustum) that it must have, and set the projection matrix accordingly.

Bad news: We don't have such control over the projection matrix in Godot 3, so this method won't work. Instead you need to make it so a `Portal` is not visible on its own `Camera` (use the `cull_mask`)…

And then you need to figure out the UVs. Because what you must see on the Portal is not the full of what the other `Camera` sees, but only the portion that corresponds to the `Portal`. I believe a shader that queries the texture using the `SCREEN_UV` will do (I haven't tried). Something like this:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = texture(TEXTURE, SCREEN_UV);
}
```

Comment: You had answered my question. I don't know why I didn't mark it as answered. It helped.